# Existence of a global solution to $y = f(y,x)$ when $f$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. By Peano theorem there exists a **local** solution to the Cauchy problem
$$ \begin{cases}
y' = f(y,x),\\
y(0) = y_0.
\end{cases} $$

If I require the condition
$$ \dfrac{d}{dx}\|y(x)\|^2 \leq K +\| y(x)\|^2, $$
also to hold on any interval where the solution is defined, global existence is guaranteed. Why is it so? What can happen if this condition is not fulfilled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating the differential inequality we obtain
$$
\|y(x)\|^2\le \|y_0\|^2e^{x}+K(e^x-1)
$$
on any interval where the solution is defined. This implies that the solution is global.

If the condition is not satisfied, the solution may blow-up in finite time. A one-dimensional example is the equation $y'=y^2$, $y(0)=y_0>0$.

Comment: The point I am missing is actually "This implies that the solution is global". Why is it so?

Comment: There are two possible behaviours for the solutions: 1) the solution is global or 2) there is a maximal interval of existence $[0,X)$ and $\lim_{x\to X^-}\|y(x)\|=\infty$. This last possibility is ruled out by the inequality.